# What is the TSQL syntax for selecting rows BETWEEN DateTime values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data in 5-minute intervals with 24-hour roll-overs, like so:

```
LogTime
-------------
7/1/2017 7:01
7/1/2017 7:06
7/1/2017 7:11
7/1/2017 7:16
...
7/2/2017 6:56
```

I need a TSQL query to select all rows for a given date, e.g. entries from `07/02 00:00:00` through `07/02 06:59:59` are considered to be part of `07/01`'s data.

I'm using this query in SSMS' editor pane:

```
SELECT * FROM [LogEntries] WHERE [LogTime] BETWEEN '20170701 06:59:59' AND '20170702 07:00'
```

The problem here is that the strings need to be logically constructed from `DateTime` values.

Can this be done in a single query statement with passed-in `DateTime` parameters? I'm doing this for an SSRS report and I'd rather not resort to a Stored Procedure if I don't have to.

Comment: Use `convert` to convert the string to a datetime. Yes, it can be done with parameters.

Comment: @Richardissimo: It's the other way 'round—the passed-in `DateTime` parameters need to be converted to strings.

Comment: If you are saying `logtime` is a kind of string, I'd strongly suggest changing that to a DateTime2. For example, any time you want to process that column you will probably need to convert it to a datetime, so why not just store it like that. Plus it will take less space to store.

Comment: @Richardissimo: It's not a string it's a `DateTime`, per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It's a `DateTime` column. See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql).

Comment: So which "strings need to be logically constructed" then?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `20170701 06:59:59` / `20170702 07:00`

Comment: So use convert from datetime to string, you just need to find [the right format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles). But I persist that storing that value as a string is a bad idea for several reasons.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Richardissimo: I'm not seeing a fit with that (CAST and CONVERT). Could you clarify? What do you have in mind?

Comment: So you want all entries for a single date, passed as a `DateTime`, where midnight untill 7AM is considered as the previous date. Is that right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'll probably end up switching to `DateTime2`, yes. But I'd like to solve this one first.

Comment: Oh  I get it. You saw example D on the between page, and thought they had to be strings. They dont. Use the datetimes you already have.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Yes, exactly. I wish I'd stated it so simply.

Comment: @Richardissimo: Aha. You read my mind.

Comment: @Richardissimo: Likely, but Zohar's got me curious. Can we wait to see what he has?

Comment: @Richardissimo: Zohar has a pretty good suggestion, but I'll probably end up doing some sort of combination of yours and his. Care to make it an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution (though not [sargable](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2016/09/13/what-is-a-sargable-predicate/), so it might not be the best) is simply to subtract 7 hours from your `LogTime` values:

```
DECLARE @DateTime DateTime = GETDATE();

SELECT * 
FROM [LogEntries] 
WHERE CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, -7, [LogTime]) AS DATE) = CAST(@DateTime AS DATE);
```

A sargable solution is a little more cumbersome, but still quite easy:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [LogEntries] 
                   -- 07 am on the date of the @DateTime variable
WHERE [LogTime] >= CAST(CAST(@DateTime AS DATE) As DateTime) + CAST('00:07:00' As DateTime) 
                 -- 07 am one day after the date of the @DateTime variable
AND  [LogTime] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(CAST(@DateTime AS DATE) As DateTime) + CAST('00:07:00' As DateTime))
```

Of course, if you pass a `Date` variable instead of a `DateTime`, it will save you one conversion (you can use + to add `datetime` values together, but not `date` + `time`, so you still must convert to `datetime`):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [LogEntries] 
                -- 7 AM
WHERE [LogTime] >= CAST(@Date As DateTime) + CAST('00:07:00' As DateTime)
                -- 7 AM on the next day
AND  [LogTime] <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(@Date As DateTime) + CAST('00:07:00' As DateTime))
```

Comment: `not sargable, so it might not be the best` I don't think that'll be much of a problem. We'll only get around 50K rows a year, so that buys us a lot of time. Great answer, thanks!

Comment: Come to think of it, I could create another column for storing the applicable date. I could put that subtraction logic in my code when I create the record. That should make it sargable.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a sargeble solution as well.

Comment: @InteXX - if you're going to *store* the applicable date and the calculation is always -7 hours, you ought to store that as a *persisted computed* column. That way, the application doesn't have to do anything. The database will compute it automatically for you.

Comment: @InteXX to add to what Damien wrote - if you store it as a *persisted* computed column, the database computes it only when the column it depends on is changed. if it's just a computed column (not persisted), the database will compute it every time you use it in a statement.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Hm...  indexing and filtering on a computed column. That sounds like a recipe for trouble. Or am I missing something? (Pardon me, I just noticed that you suggested *persisted* as well. Never mind. Good suggestion, if I can get it to work with EF Code First Migrations.)

Comment: @ZoharPeled: That sounds interesting, but I'm using EF Code First Migrations. I don't know that there's a way to get it to ignore a manually-created column already in the table, but I'll look into it. Hope so.

Comment: You can always add sargables conditions `LogTime between @Date and date(hour, 31, @Date)` which are "close supersets" of the one you really want.

Answer (score 4):

The question states "The problem here is that the strings need to be logically constructed from DateTime values".

In the [BETWEEN (Transact-sql) documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/between-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#d-using-between-with-datetime-values) cited by the OP, example D (for datetimes) says this:

> **D. Using BETWEEN with datetime values**
>
> The following example retrieves rows in which datetime values are between '20011212' and '20020105', inclusive.
>
> SELECT BusinessEntityID, RateChangeDate
>   FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory
>   WHERE RateChangeDate BETWEEN '20011212' AND '20020105';

This makes it seem that the DateTime values needs to be supplied as strings. They don't. You can use datetimes.

Zohar's answer addresses the time-shifting part of the problem.

Comment: While your mind-reading skills are impressive, Unfortunately I don't see how this provide an answer to the actual question. I'm not downvoting your answer but I did flag it as NAA.